# How do I let user 'Y' write in folder 'A' only when executing script 'X'?

Tags: linux, permissions, script, user

How do I let user **Y** write in folder **A** only when executing script **X**?

Answer (score 4):

I believe that this will require program X having setuid permissions, and belonging to a user UA that has write privileges to folder A. Then when X is invoked it runs as UA, no matter what user it was invoked by.

Most shells (maybe all) won't let scripts have setuid permissions, they'll just ignore that permission bit unless X is a binary. of course x could be a binary wrapper that just executes some separate script X.sh.

You shouldn't setuid X as *root* if you don't have to. You could make folder A be writable by a user UA with less privileges.

Alternatively, you could make folder A be writable by a dedicated group, and assign X to that group, and use setgid on X instead of setuid.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is commonly faced by games - nethack for example has "bones" files and a hiscore table that should be writable by the game but not by any of the individual non-administrator users. This is done by having the executable setgid.

http://nethack.wikia.com/wiki/Setgid has a rundown on this system. The advantage is that an exploit of nethack would only get you group games privileges, rather user root privileges.

Answer (score 0):

How about having script **x** write to /usr/bin, but as user **z** which is a user account for this specific purpose?

Granted, this means using the sticky bit, which has its own security concerns, but you can lock down user **z** (no logins, very restricted permissions beyond /usr/bin, etc.)

I'm not the best on Linux security, but it was the only thing I could come up with on short notice.

A lot of applications execute privilege separation--they do everything they can as an unprivileged user and then the one or two operations that require root are actually done by a separate process. (Alternately: start as root, do the one-two things that require root, and drop privileges.)

Your other option, off the top of my head, is sudo.